# Event atStart App?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm starting writing my little app at WP7. I consider one thing. There is event "AtStart"? I want to use Textbox to display actual data with some text and I thought that event "atstart/atLaunch" will be perfect for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no "AtStart" event - there is an `Application.Launching` event which is fired when your application starts up. There is also an `OnNavigatedTo` virtual method you can override on a page level which is invoked when a page is first navigated to. It sounds like `OnNavigatedTo` might be what you are looking for. At this point you can change the Text property of a `TextBlock` (which is identified by an `x:Name`) which is present in your page XAML file.